# What's wrong with this linq outer join that joins multiple tables?

Tags: c#, linq, join

This is my first time doing an outer join with LINQ.  I think my query is close, but it's returning a lot more rows than it should.  The SQL created by the LINQ query is returning 2522 records while the sql equivalent shown below is only returning 8 which is the correct number.  The iqid in the linq query is being set by a constant to isolate this one record for my test case.

I would also like to know why the two bool evaluations in the where statement don't work.  The first one does, but the other two are commented out because they wouldn't compile.  I tried using the "==" like the first statement and 0 instead of false, but neither worked.

What is wrong with this query?

Linq:

```
public const string iqid = "9C01FFAE9B4E43D7853D811C8CF77B09";

var outerJoinQuery = from n in context.VCNOTE

                 // join the other table in and project into IEnumerable "noteGroup"
                 join l in context.VCNOTELINKS on n.IQID equals l.NOTE into noteGroup
                 from l in noteGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 join c in context.SFACONTACT on l.CONTACT equals c.FIRSTNAME into contactGroup
                 from c in contactGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 join f in context.VCFUND on l.FUND equals f.IQID into fundGroup
                 from f in fundGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 join d in context.VCPROJECT on l.PROJECT equals d.LIBELLE into dealGroup
                 from d in dealGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 join a in context.SFAACCOUNT on l.ACCOUNT equals a.NAME into companyGroup
                 from a in companyGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                 where n.IQID == iqid // && n.IQDELETED = false && l.IQDELETED = false

                 // project to an anonymous type and set properties to be displayed
                 select new
                 {
                     NoteID = l.NOTE,
                     FundID = l.FUND,
                     FundName = f.FUND,
                     ContactID = l.CONTACT,
                     ContactName = c.FIRSTNAME,
                     CompanyID = l.ACCOUNT,
                     CompanyName = a.NAME,
                     DealID = d.IQID,
                     DealName = d.LIBELLE
                 };
```

This is what the sql I created (not produced by linq query) looks like which returns 8 rows and is the expected result.  This is also what the sql created by linq should be like:

```
select  L.[IQID]
    ,L.[IQDELETED]
    ,L.[NOTE]           'Linked NoteID'
    ,L.[FUND]           'Linked FundID'
    ,F.Fund             'Linked Fund'
    ,L.[ACCOUNT]            'Linked CompanyID'
    ,A.NAME             'Linked Company'
    ,L.[PROJECT]            'Linked DealID'
    ,D.LIBELLE          'Linked Deal'
    ,L.[CONTACT]            'Linked ContactID'
    ,CONCAT(C.FIRSTNAME,' ',C.LASTNAME) 'Linked Contact' 

FROM VCNOTELINKS L

LEFT OUTER JOIN VCFUND F ON L.FUND = F.IQID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SFAACCOUNT A ON L.ACCOUNT = A.IQID
LEFT OUTER JOIN VCPROJECT D ON L.PROJECT = D.IQID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SFACONTACT C ON L.CONTACT = C.IQID

where L.note = '9C01FFAE9B4E43D7853D811C8CF77B09' AND L.IQDELETED = 0
```

Comment: Instead of joins you should use navigation properties https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Wouldn't it be so much easier just to create a VIEW in your database with all of your joins optimized for you?

Comment: BTW, your last two conditions in your where clause are doing assignment, not equality check.  Should be `n.IQDELETED == false && l.IQDELETED == false`

Comment: You need an 'into' like in the example on webpage shown.  Your where is only being applied to the last object "from a in companyGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()" instead of the entire join. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b